# Does Firebase Storage's getMetaData() call the backend (and thus introduce a small delay)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage

I currently use the following (Swift 4) code to download an image stored on the Firebase Storage :

```
func getImage(completion: @escaping (UIImage?)->()) {
    let ref = Storage.storage().reference().child("myImage.jpg")
    ref.getMetadata() {
        (metadata, error) in
        guard let url = metadata?.downloadURLs?.first, error == nil else {
            print(String(describing: error))
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        //got url download image here and return it
        //this function is not important but it does it asynchroniously
        func downloadImageOrReturnACachedVersionOfItBy(url, completion)
    }
```

I notice a considerable delay in downloading the image, even if `downloadImageOrReturnACachedVersionOfItBy(...)` actually takes care of image cashing

Questions:

1. Does the function `getMetadata()` contact the backend each time its called? 
   And thus can this introduce a round-trip web service calling delay?
2. If so...to avoid this, would it be a good idea store the returned url, when the image was uploaded, returned in the metadata from Firebase `putData()` locally in the app? Are these download url's fixed for life? Are the automatically being invalidated somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Does the function getMetadata() contact the backend each time its
>   called? And thus can this introduce a round-trip web service calling
>   delay?

Yes, this is because the download URL may have changed (e.g. developer revoked it), so we need to fetch it again.

Note that we have a [downloadURL() method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url) that does the same thing but without you having to parse metadata manually.

> 2) If so...to avoid this, would it be a good idea store the returned
>   url, when the image was uploaded, returned in the metadata from
>   Firebase putData() locally in the app? Are these download url's fixed
>   for life? Are the automatically being invalidated somehow?

I'd recommend using the [FirebaseUI integration with SDWebImage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui), which automatically caches and displays these images.

```
// Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
let reference = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")

// UIImageView in your ViewController
let imageView: UIImageView = self.imageView

// Placeholder image
let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")

// Load the image using SDWebImage
imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using the getMethadata() because this also returns the modified timestamp and I am using this to check agains a local cache module I have implemented to see if the file needs redownloading.

I am not using the SDWebImage because its to basic for me, I have implemented a complete caching system to local disk myself that is clever enough to see if the image needs redownloading or if the cached disk version is used. To get around the delay of the getMethadata I am now always showing the cached version (if any) and updating it should the file on FB be newer...